# Query to select between two dates without year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update certain fields for employees whose date of joining falls in between 10 Jun and 31 Dec, irrespective of the year. I am trying using 'Between' Operator but it requires year to be included in the dates. Is there a way to generalise it in order to consider Day and Month excluding the Year?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Post your table structure

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use between. Have you looked at DatePart to pull out the bits of the date you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DatePart function - replace thedate with your column, and thetable with the column.

Something like this:

```
select  datepart(MONTH, thedate),  datepart(DAY, thedate),*
from  thetable
where  datepart(MONTH, thedate) between 6 and 12
and  datepart(DAY, thedate) between 10 and 31
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had a doubt whether the days will correspond to the months in the same order, but its working. Thanks :)

Comment: `datepart(MONTH, thedate) >= 6 and datepart(DAY, thedate) >= 10` is enough right. No need of between operator

Comment: @Santhosh - in this case the between isn't really needed, but makes it a more general solution and probably easier to read the intent, or change to use different day ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
WITH Emp AS (
  SELECT *, DATEPART(MONTH, JoinDate) AS MonthJoin, DATEPART(DAY, JoinDate) AS DayJoin
  FROM Employees)
SELECT *
FROM Emp
WHERE (MonthJoin > 1 AND MonthJoin < 12)
  OR (MonthJoin = 1 AND DayJoin >= 10)
  OR (MonthJoin = 12 AND DayJoin <= 31)
```

Where `Employees` is your table and `JoinDate` is your date of joining in this table